# Styling individual lines in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forum

I'm making a php mysqli forum, and i would like users to be able to style their posts so it doesn't look so dull.

I want some basic buttons, like [Header1,Header,Header3,Normal,] and also [italic,bold,underlined]

I now have two questions,

1.
How do I make the buttons and style the textarea?

How do i get styled text into a mysql db?

Thanks in advance.

Daniel Holst

Comment: Using some editor like CkEditor can help.

Comment: I would like to do this myself, without implementing a complete libary

Comment: So you have to code a complete editor like the one I suggested to you or this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use things like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), it as all the things you need and manymore. It will make you textarea a full richtext editor.
You can't do it as is without any javascript.
You can use another editor.

To get styled texte from you database, you need to  save the text with the formatting before restoring it.

Comment: +1 after your editing, better this way.